# CSS animation not starting on Firefox, "blinking" on Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Trying to implement a css animation. I've defined colors in :root like so

```css
:root {
  --c1: rgb(225, 225, 0);
  --c2: rgb(199, 199, 198);
  --c3: rgb(225, 225, 0);
  --c4: rgb(255, 167, 209);
  --c5: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}
```

the animation is in the background id:

```css
#background {
  transition: --c1 0.1s ease-out, --c2 0.1s ease-out, --c3 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: --c1 0.1s ease-out, --c2 0.1s ease-out, --c3 0.1s ease-out;
  animation: anim 30s ease infinite normal;

  background: -o-radial-gradient(var(--c1) 15%, var(--c2) 25%, var(--c3) 45%, var(--c4) 55%, var(--c5) 75%);
  background: radial-gradient(var(--c1) 15%, var(--c2) 25%, var(--c3) 45%, var(--c4) 55%, var(--c5) 75%);

  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -3;
}
```

and these are my keyframes -

```css
@keyframes anim {
  from {  
    --c1: rgb(225, 225, 0);
    --c2: rgb(199, 199, 198);
    --c3: rgb(225, 225, 0);
    --c4: rgb(255, 167, 209);
    --c5: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  }
  20% {
    --c1: rgb(199, 199, 198);
    --c2: rgb(255, 167, 209);
    --c3: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    --c4: rgb(255, 167, 209);
    --c5: rgb(199, 199, 198);
  }
  30% {
    --c2: rgb(245, 64, 41);
  }
  40% {
    --c1: rgb(245, 64, 41);
    --c2: rgb(255, 167, 209);
    --c3: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    --c4: rgb(255, 167, 209);
    --c5: rgb(199, 199, 198);
  }
  45% {
    --c4: rgb(255, 167, 209);
  }
  50% {
    --c1: rgb(255, 167, 209);
    --c2: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    --c3: rgb(255, 167, 209);
    --c4: rgb(199, 199, 198);
    --c5: rgb(255, 167, 209);
  }
  80% {
    --c1: rgb(199, 199, 198);
    --c2: rgb(225, 225, 0);
    --c3: rgb(255, 167, 209);
    --c4: rgb(199, 199, 198);
    --c5: rgb(255, 167, 209);
  }
  90% {
    --c1: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    --c3: rgb(225, 225, 0);
  }
  to {
    --c1: rgb(225, 225, 0);
    --c2: rgb(199, 199, 198);
    --c3: rgb(225, 225, 0);
    --c4: rgb(255, 167, 209);
    --c5: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  }
```

I also have parts for @-moz-keyframes anim{} and @-webkit-keyframes anim {} with the same contents (this seems to be a problem in a lot of similar questions)

When I open it in Chrome, the animation starts but the transitions are not smooth, it's "bliking" from one state to another and in Firefox it just stays in the first state. Tried different timing, but it stays the same

I tried to look into dev tools on Firefox and Chrome to see the animation property - Chrome just says Waiting for animations (using npm dev so maybe that broke it); Firefox shows a timeline which lasts for the right duration and shows it happening in #background but nothing shows up in the timeline.

In the start I had the colors defined in @property and that worked in Chrome, but isn't supported in most Firefox versions yet, thats why I switched

I'm at the end of my wits, thanks for the help!

Comment: Provide an example code that reproduces the problem!